# How to diagnose graphics card crashes in debian-based systems?

Tags: ubuntu, crash, vga

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 in a Xeon pc with a good number of cheap and unreliable hardware.

The graphics card is a GT 710, sometimes part of the monitors connected to it are not recognized as expected, so I feel the graphics card is my bigger problem at the moment.

My main issue is that sometimes the pc freezes, both in locked state and while I'm using, I can see my desktop environment completely frozen if pc is unlocked, but I can't do anything to recover from it. I need to hard reset or turn off and on again.

kern.log is clean, and these are the last syslog lines from last crash:

```
May  3 02:31:38 jackiechan systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
May  3 02:31:38 jackiechan NetworkManager[1207]: <info>  [1683091898.9461] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
May  3 02:31:48 jackiechan systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
May  3 02:39:01 jackiechan CRON[128119]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
May  3 02:39:01 jackiechan systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
May  3 02:39:01 jackiechan systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Deactivated successfully.
May  3 02:39:01 jackiechan systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
May  3 02:42:45 jackiechan google-chrome.desktop[6111]: [0503/024245.646497:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /home/lamps/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/pending/cdef4c72-fe2f-43a6-82ff-a257c6deaca4.lock: F>
May  3 02:44:31 jackiechan NetworkManager[1207]: <info>  [1683092671.4595] dhcp4 (enp5s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.31.157
May  3 02:57:45 jackiechan google-chrome.desktop[6111]: [0503/025745.646747:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /home/lamps/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/pending/cdef4c72-fe2f-43a6-82ff-a257c6deaca4.lock: F>
May  3 14:46:19 jackiechan kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x49, date = 2021-08-11
```

So nothing looks terrible to me in here. Is there some utility available to diagnose graphics card issues, like a memtest or smart, but for GPUs?

Oh, I've also installed a Debian 11 in a different SSD, same pc, and got this freeze in first day. Didn't check logs in that distro, but to me it reinforces I'm facing some hardware issue.

Some context on hardware: Worst graphics card brand, bought in the pandemic using the criteria of supporting 3 monitors and being nVidia as I dislike AMD drivers. I also have the worst motherboard brand, bought in the pandemics because I'm broke. Using DDR4 ECC parts, I'm using 2 x 16GB but have some spare substitutes.